# Would it be possible so that several consecutive underscores in a question are displayed verbatim?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

At [Why is my iOS app taking a long time to load on my device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984084/why-is-my-ios-app-taking-a-long-time-to-load-on-my-device) , if you pull it up in the editor, you will see 12 underscores (appearing twice) in "Waiting for ____________: ____________'s iPhone to launch"; but the rendered display is as below: three underscores as quoted above.

I know that underscores can be used Markdown-style to emphasize text and should not be displayed, but several underscores in a row are intended as standard literal placeholders. The phrase quoted above could be replaced by "Waiting for XYZ: ABC's iPhone to launch", but a placeholder represented by several underscores is a fairly standard feature.

Is there a way, without disrupting standard wrapping in underscores to emphasize text, to let several consecutive underscores displayed verbatim as a usual placeholder?

Thanks,

Comment: what if I want a sequnce of bolded or italicised underscores? (OK, hopefully noone wants italicised underscores)

Comment: 4 underscores should be enough for anybody.

Comment: *_* **_** ***_*** ***`_`*** . @Jan - I don't think that this font has styling for underscores. :)

Comment: You can use backslashes to escape the outer underscores: \_____\_ At least in comments it even works without: ______

Comment: @user7116 - surely you mean 64 underscores.

Comment: @Oded: I'm in a hurry to be obsolete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not certain why so many underscores are necessary, but if you deem them to be necessary:

```
"Waiting for \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ : \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_'s iPhone to launch."
```

Rendered as so, "Waiting for ____________ : ____________'s iPhone to launch."

See [Markdown Syntax: Backslash Escapes](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash).